# Change background color on mousehover javascript

Tags: javascript, hover

If I had the following html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="http://www.google.com" class="google">google.com</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How could I use JavaScript to change the background colour everytime the mouse hovers over the link? I know you can use the `onmousehover` event but it never seems to work.

Comment: Why not just use CSS `:hover`?

Answer (score 1):

you could simply do,

```
a:hover {
    background: red;
}
```